# Получение @имя_пользователя в телеграмм для команды /hug

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

я создал команду /hug в своем телеграмм боте, чтобы кого-то обнять нужно вписать /hug @имя_пользователя. Но если написать просто /hug, бот напишет в чате, (тут ничего не будет) вас обнял @мой_ник.

А мне нужно чтобы он работал, если я напишу именно /hug @имя_пользователя
Если просто /hug то бот выдаст Ошибка введите /hug @имя_пользователя.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['hug', 'обнять', 'обнимашки', 'обнял'])
def hugCommand(message):
    hugtarget = extract_arg(message.text)
    #chat_id = message.from_user.id
    #message_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    # Hug Image
    hugimg = nekos.img('hug')
    #bot.send_message(chat_id, '{hugtarget} вас обнял {username}')
   # bot.reply_to(message, f" ".join(hugtarget) + " вас обнял @" + username + f'\n{hugimg}')
    bot.send_animation(message.chat.id, hugimg, caption=f" ".join(hugtarget) + " вас обнял(а) @" + username)

Ну, если ещё можно чтобы я на ответ в сообщение просто написал /hug и бот написал ник того кому я ответил, если просто /hug не в ответ на сообщение то Ошибка введите /hug @имя_пользователя
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### upd:

```
import telebot
from telebot.util import extract_arguments
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['hug', 'обнять', 'обнимашки', 'обнял'])
def hugCommand(message):
    hugtarget = extract_arguments(message.text)
    your_id = message.from_user.id
    your_name = message.from_user.username
    hugimg = nekos.img('hug')
    if not hugtarget:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Введите /hug @имя_пользователя')
    else:
      bot.send_animation(message.chat.id, hugimg, caption=f'[{hugtarget}], вас обнял [{your_name}](tg://user?id={str(your_id)})', parse_mode="Markdown")
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я использую Telebot

Ещё мне нужно чтобы была анимация ибо у меня с гифкой, где я юзаю библиотеку nekos.py

Comment: Что-то не правильно. Пишет все равно "вас обнял(а) @riktik_official"
Ну работает как моя команда, если ничего не написать напишет "вас обнял(а) @riktik_official",  а если к примеру test напишет "test вас обнял(а) @riktik_official", в другом случае если написать @имя бот отправит - "@имя вас обнял(а) @riktik_official"

Comment: @Riktik, еще раз обновил код, проверил у себя - работает так как вам нужно, проверьте

Comment: Спасибо, работает отлично, но все равно проблема если напишу /hug и к примеру слово бебра

Бот напишет бебра вас обнял @мой_ник

https://imgur.com/qv71E6q

Comment: Ещё, я все таки решил перейти на библиотеку aiogram, из-за того что с TeleBot я всегда заморачиваюсь, ибо информацию для Telebot сложно найти нормальную, в отличии от aiogram